# Is a SQLite database is something that exist on my computer when developing an app with core data or each iPhone have an SQLite instalment?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I know, this is a super beginner question, but i'm a super beginner so please be kind and help me to get this right.

for the past 4 months i'v learned some c and java to get my programming of the ground, then started to learn objective-c and im learning to develop simple apps currently with the apple documentation guids, so I built a simple app and leaning now how to persist its data and save it to a database (which is probably the same thing :/).

Now, i'v never used a database before, and i'm wondering, when I build an app that use SQLite database (i guess it's the default database in core data), is the database is something that is created on the machine that developed the app, or each iPhone have a database instalment that is on the device to persist it's data..?

Would love to have any information possible, thanks a bunch!

Comment: The SQLite database is simply a file that is created and stored within your app. It's not on your development machine. It's not "an installment on the iPhone". It's just a file in the app.

Comment: @rmaddy so each iPhone (or smartphone in general) holds those files in their memory? I wish apple would provide this info when they teach you how to develop. I guess they assume if you learning how to develop you probably familiar with it, but i'm sure it's not always the case

Comment: If you are a complete beginner to iOS I strongly recommend you follow the "Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad" on iTunesU.  This is a Stanford course that will help you enormously by showing you how to write an app and answering questions you never knew you had.

Comment: No, that's not it at all. And it is not Apple's job to teach you how a computer works.

Comment: @RoboticCat thank you, I actually took some of the tutorials there for different subjects, but for some other subjects I used ray wenderlich site.

Comment: @RoboticCat what do you mean it's not it at all? I'd appreciate if you can direct me to where i can read about it

Comment: I think you mean @rmaddy but SQLite is a database file that exists on disk (once you create it). At times, objects or records may be in memory but the bulk of all data will be on disk and retrieved on demand. Also, it is unlikely you will use SQLite directly but rather through CoreData (as a persistent store). See here:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on some Core Data stuff and yes, there is a SQLite database on my development machine. When you create the DB (you are really creating a Managed Document that holds the database) you specify a file name and path within the app's file space.  You have to find where that sits in the development machine file system.  Here's where one of mine sits - obviously yours will not be in the same place but it gives you an idea...

/Users/leecea/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/F4AC4CDC-4726-4D0E-B6C6-55F0F5C63BB4/Documents/CMDatabaseDir/CMDatabase/StoreContent/persistentStore

I am running SQLite Manager and can examine or update the database to help debug my app.

When you push the app out to a device, it will create an instance of the DB on each device, in a file in the app's sandbox.  They are not connected back to the one on your machine.

Maybe there are more technically correct answers, but this visualization works for me :)